# Editing rows in an interactive report using Oracle APEX 5

Tags: report, interactive, oracle-apex-5

Hi I am trying to edit the rows of interactive reports in APEX 5. I know we can do that in earlier versions, by chaning the properties in "tabular form attributes tab", but I am not able to find a way to do that in APEX5. 
I am getting 5 rows as a result and I want 1 of the column to be editable and that should point to a select list (LOV).

Can you please help me on this.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you want to use Interactive Grid - this is the killing feature of Apex 5. It replaces the tabular forms.

Comment: I agree. Although, I somehow don't like the Interactive Grid "as is" right now. The most annoying thing is *stupid* column width. That's why I - sometimes - rather create an *oldfashioned* tabular form. On the other hand, I like its editing capabilities. Didn't switch to 18.x yet, maybe those good & nice Oracle enthusiasts improved the IG.